# creating pdf from obj c for an iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf

I need to generate a `PDF` file on click of a button that pdf should takes the contents from `database` and I have to view my generated `PDF` file once its generated how can I do this? can anyone guide me to some good material for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should start from iOS Developer Library:

[PDF Document Creation, Viewing, and Transforming](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html)